# Final static field serialization

Tags: java, serialization, interface, static, final

Recently, I've been reading about serialization and everything looks pretty understandable. Values with `final` keyword are serialized, `static` values are not serialized, in `static transient`, `transient` is ignored so on and so on. I have read almost everything, but I have one question, for which I could not find the answer, not in google nor on Stack Overflow:

What happens when data is `static final`? Which one of them overcomes the other? For example:

```java
interface Foo{
    int value = 10; // by default it is public static final
}
```

How will the value from that interface be serialized, if i implement it in any of my classes? Will it be treated as `final` or `static`?

Comment: `final` does not mean that it will be serialized (or not). As specified: "Default serializable fields of a class are defined to be the non-transient and non-static fields." (see [Defining Serializable Fields for a Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#a6250))

Comment: From the aspect of your question `static` is used/has precedence... since `final` is not/barely related to serialization... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

Comment: `static` values are not serialized.

Comment: @user85421 your answer helped me. somewhere i read that final fields are serialized seems i misunderstood something. if i understood correctly now. static final value = 10 will not be serialized.

Answer (score 2):

A **static final** variable will not be serialized, since just like a **static** variable,is a class variable independent of instances. The **final** modifier states only that once the variable is assigned, it can no longer be changed

Comment: `final` isn't that simple (but OK for given context); "A blank final class variable must be definitely assigned by a static initializer ... A blank final instance variable must be definitely assigned and moreover not definitely unassigned at the end of every constructor of the class in which it is declared"

Comment: @Vito my question and your answer do not match each other . i asked totally different thing

Comment: @Anuka haven't you asked "what happens when data is static final?" So isn't "A **static final** variable will not be serialized" an answer? totally different??